# Monitor displays after 10 minutes

Tags: display

I have hp 7550 monitor, monitor displays screen after 10 minutes and continuously sounds like spark from inside the body, sometimes the light pink shades also appear, does anyone have solution?

Comment: There isn't enough information here for anybody to be able to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: What else information do you need?

Comment: This is ancient technology that is way past its service life.  It sounds like the problem is in the monitor.  There is not likely anything you could do to fix it yourself.  Even if it is repairable, you can replace it with a better, new, modern monitor for less than the cost of having a technician diagnose the problem and repair it.

Comment: A quick scan of Amazon.com shows a bunch of 1920x1080 monitors (slightly more total resolution than yours in a modern aspect ratio), all with larger screens, in the price range of $105-$140, including shipping.

Comment: "sounds like spark from inside the body" Unplug it before you start a fire. Then dispose of it properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is a 17" crt style monitor? You could replace it , even with the many other CRT monitors that are being recycled and still very usable. A newer LCD monitor could save as much electrical utility costs over its lifetime to pay for itself.

Any of the issues with colors being hugely wrong, like whites being majenta, or yellow or cyan, can be caused Only by a simple cable connection issue, because unlike a digital monitor, the analog is sent in 3 seperate connecting lines Red green and blue (and sync) so if whole colors are messing up, check the cables and check for bent pins.

A simple dust cleaning could be easily done with lots of compressed air, with a air compressor like you would have at a gas station, and a high velocity nozzel. very minimal cleaning could be accomplished with a can of compressed air.  Any dissasembly would require great caution.

-----Below this line is at your own risk , not really the smartest thing, just possible ----

Disclaimer: electrocution risk, loss of all function of the monitor if not done properly.  You could be killed , and you could kill what is left of the monitor.

A CRT uses a very high voltage to fire electrons in the tube, dust and layers of slime like kitchen grease, road film , smoke residue and all can create contact with various high-voltage areas of them, and begin to arc, eventually destroying things. Paths of high voltage arcing then form carbon resistive paths increasing the problem , by conducting even more energy to places.

It is possible to completly clean the inside of a CRT and (only) possibly reduce internal problems caused by stuff in there (If that was part of the problem). I have cleaned many before, and would give the chance of survival of one already having problems like that at ~40%, and not worth the trouble.  I would usually clean and or dust them well before they start to die.
  I have cleared some up and had them live long happy lives, and others there was zero change in the behaviour, and components would have had to be replaced, like flyback transformers and capacitors.

You must first recognise there are very high voltages at currents that can be deadly stored up in the capcitors and the tube.  Trained techs and idiots like me will wait with it unplugged for a day which mostly discharges everything, then  use discharging methods to insure they do not get shocked (it is not fun).  The main picture tube is discharged to ground using insulated probes, designed to keep the human from getting near the high voltage.

After clearing out all the power, cleaning chemicals like tech sprays ($$$), houshold ammonia, and 90% + alcohol can be used to clean the internal surfaces of the PCBs and all. (again assuming that was the problem)  Finishing up with lots of 90%+ (not proof) isopropyl alcohol to displace most of the water, drying with an air compressor, then letting it dry for at least 2 Weeks.

after 2 weeks I use an extention cord , plug it in while standing back from it (chicken) let it run for some time, then put it back into service.

Comment: If successful, there is satisfaction in knowing that you eeked a little more life out of the thing without incurring injury.  You can't put a price on that, or the bragging rights of doing your computer work on a functioning museum piece.